# Variant Array Custom Function Google Sheets? VBA For Example

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, user-defined-functions, dynamic-arrays, variant-array

The following function below will add "1" to every column across the excel sheet. If I put =vbe(12) in A1, it will put "1" in columns "A1:L1". How can I translate this VBA to JavaScript for Google Sheets?

```
Function vbe(Num As Long) As Variant
   Dim ary As Variant
   Dim i As Long
   ReDim ary(Num - 1)
   For i = 0 To Num - 1
      ary(i) = 1
   Next i
   vbe = ary
End Function
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can write a custom formula that creates an array of "1"s with the length as a specified parameter, e.g.

```
function myFunction(numberColumns) {
  var ones=[];
  ones[0]=[];
  for(var i=0;i<numberColumns;i++){
    ones[0].push(1);
  }
  return ones;
}
```

Now, you just need to call the function from a cell, e.g. by typing

`=myFunction(12)`

Useful information can be found in the documentation about [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) and [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/custom-functions).

Comment: Thank you so much!