# Seeking help in custom function returning a two-dimensional array that can overflow

Tags: google-apps-script

To minimize the number of calls, I am trying to use a single call to a function and populate a range (with multiple cells). My function 'getTotal' below is working fine but I am stuck in 'You do not have permission to call setValue'. The range I am trying to populated is C4: C12 (please see attached screen) and I am passing =getTotal(A4: A12, B4: B12) to the function. The function is called from C16.

We can't call setValue from a custom function but I am not sure whether I can return a two-dimensional array that can overflow into the C4: C12. Documentations and answers here did not help me so I am seeking help.

[image]

```
function getTotal(oSetVal, vRange) {

  if (Array.isArray(oSetVal[0]) && Array.isArray(vRange[0])) {
    var asp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    if (!asp) {
      return;
    }
    var as = asp.getActiveSheet();
    var ss = asp.getSheetByName("Data")
    if (!ss) {
      return;
    }
    if (Array.isArray(oSetVal[0]) && Array.isArray(vRange[0])) {
        var activeCol = as.getActiveCell().getColumn();
        var numCol = activeCol-1
        var textCol = activeCol-2
        var drRow = as.getActiveCell().getRow()-4;
        var textRowStart = drRow - 15;
        var cSource = ss.getRange(3, 2, 5000, 1).getValues();
        var cKcal = ss.getRange(3, 4, 5000, 1).getValues();
        var vEnergy = 0;

        if (textRowStart < 3){
            textRowStart = 3;
        }
        var textRowEnd = drRow
        var textSource = as.getRange(textRowStart, textCol, textRowEnd, 1)
        var numSource = as.getRange(textRowStart, numCol, textRowEnd, 1)
        var numSource = as.getRange(textRowStart, numCol, textRowEnd, 1)
        var setSource = as.getRange(textRowStart, activeCol, textRowEnd, 1)
        for (var k = 1; k <= textRowEnd-textRowStart; k++) {
            var tVal = textSource.getCell(k,1).getValue();
            var nVal = numSource.getCell(k,1).getValue();
            if (tVal.length > 0 && isNumericVal(nVal)) {
                for (var i = 0; i < cSource.length; i++) {
                    if(cSource[i][0] == tVal){
                        var ckl = cKcal[i][0];
                        var vEn = parseFloat((ckl * nVal / 100))
                        vEn = +vEn.toFixed(1)
                        vEnergy = vEnergy + vEn
                        setSource.getCell(k,1).setValue(vEn); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

  return vEnergy
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can only overflow down and right. Not up and to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If you want to keep using a custom function:

You need to use `return values` instead of `setValues()`. You are not allowed to set the value of arbitrary cells from a custom formula.

Also, as pointed out by [@Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091/cooper) "You can return a 2D array, but it can only overflow down and right. Not up and to the left". Meaning **you cannot overflow upwards, but only downwards.**

This means that you need to call your function from the cell **C4** rather than from **C16**.

In order to modify your formula and enable overflow, you need to create a 2D-array of the required dimensions.

In your case 1 column and 9 rows will set all `vEn` values. You could also use 13 rows if you want to set both `vEn` and `vEnergy` in one go.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59582000/11599789) for a sample on how to do this.

#### Applying the sample to your case:

You can define at the beginning of your function:
`var myArray = [];`

and then replace the inside of your for loop (`setSource.getCell(k,1).setValue(vEn);`) with

```
myArray[k] = [];
myArray[k].push(vEn);
```

And finally replace `return vEnergy` with:

```
myArray[12].push(vEnergy);
return myArray;
```

---

*I did not test your code given that I do not have access to "Data", but I hope that my answer helps you to modify your code in the desired way.*

Comment: Very helpful, it helped me a lot to understand the Google script better.

Comment: I am glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

A custom function cannot affect cells other than those it returns a value to. In other words, a custom function cannot edit arbitrary cells, only the cells it is called from and their adjacent cells. To edit arbitrary cells, use a custom menu to run a function instead.

You can return a 2D array, but it can only overflow down and right. Not up and to the left.

Comment: Yes, and I am seeking a help in "returning a two-dimensional array that can overflow"